# Xcode simulator resolution for iphone 6

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

When I use the simulator set for the iPhone 6 for one xcode project the screen width is 320. However, when I use the simulator for another project the screen with is 375. Is there a way to change the screen width back from 375 to 320?

[image]

Comment: For the iphone 6, the screen width is always 375 points, both for the simulator and for real devices. Are you sure you are using the iphone 6 sim in both projects? Btw, take a look at this cool link to learn more: http://www.paintcodeapp.com/news/iphone-6-screens-demystified

Comment: I literally ran one project after the next. So the simulator didn't change. First I got 320 and then I got 370 when testing the screen width

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot?

Comment: Screen shot provided. I run one app it gives me 375 as the width. I run my other app on the same simulator it give me 320

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a launch image for the iPhone 6 or add a launch screen storyboard. Your app will run at iPhone 5 resolution and scale it up on larger devices if you don't.

Comment: You saved my life! Thanks man that was definitely it, my other app has a launch image.

Answer (score 2):

Try  ⌘+1,  ⌘+2,  ⌘+3,  ⌘+4,  ⌘+5

Does it helped?